# Android testing: how to check a dialog is displayed on screen? (using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2)

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm trying to finally add UI tests to my Android application, to increase coverage (all my other layers are properly tested, hence all my bugs now come from the UI...)
I started to use `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` as my base class for emulator unit-tests, and simple things are easy to check and work nice.

But now, I'm trying to check a Dialog appears as expected, and I don't know how to do that.

My test:

```
public void testOpensAboutDialogWhenAboutButtonClicked() {
    final MyActivity activity = getActivity();
    final Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

    final Button aboutButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.about);
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, aboutButton);

    // how to test for the AboutDialog?
}
```

Now my dialog doesn't have an id, so I can't get a pointer to it using findViewById.
It has been created using the builder classes available:

```
final AlertDialog about = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent)
            .setTitle(parent.getString(R.string.about_title))
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.skull)
            ....
```

Any ideas, or pointers to tutorials?

**EDIT:** To answer Jens comment, I'm **not** using managed dialogs, just creating the AlertDialog and showing it with .show()

Comment: Are you using managed dialogs?

Comment: @Jens, Actually I'm not, I didn't even know about them... I just read about them, and that might help solving my problem indeed... (That will teach me to skip the tutorials...) Will try tonight. If that does it, please write an answer so I can give you the bounty ;)

Comment: I can give you a proper answer btw.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you're already using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` you should start using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) - it will simplify your testing **a lot**.

For your case it's as easy as this (if you know the expected title or something else vaguely unique about your dialog):

```
public void testSomeRandomSentence() {
    Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    // Now do whatever you need to do to trigger your dialog.

    // Let's assume a properly lame dialog title.
    assertTrue("Could not find the dialog!", solo.searchText("My Dialog Title"));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll check it out.

Comment: Alright, this looks promising, definitely the way to go for me. Congratulations, you win the bounty!

Comment: So this was not working for me when using Robotium. I think the issue was maybe that I was using an old style dialog (as opposed to a `DialogFragment`) and somehow this was not connected to the view hierarcy in the same way so `solo.searchText(..)` could not find it. I fixed this by using a `DialogFragment` and using Robotiums `solo.waitForFragmentByTag(...)` method - which now works great :)

Answer (score 1):

after assigning id to Toast in setUp() by

```
toast = (Toast)activity.findViewById(..........);
```

create testcase()
{

```
ViewAsserts.assertOnScreen(toasts.getRootView(), toast.getRootView());
//pass if toast is visible on screen
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not a Toast, it's an AlertDialog, and the whole point of my question was that it doesn't have an id, so I can't use findViewById, and I can't get a reference to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

add a getter to your dialog like :

```
public AlertDialog get_aboutbox()
{
   return this.about;
}
```

then here the solution for your test :

```
public void testOpensAboutDialogWhenAboutButtonClicked() {
    final MyActivity activity = getActivity();

    assertNotNull("aboutbox is null",activity.get_aboutbox());
    final Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

    final Button aboutButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.about);
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, aboutButton);

    assertTrue("About Button didn't displayed the Dlg",
               activity.get_aboutbox().isShowing());
}
```